# Reactjs - read an image from url in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a project which I read objects from a json file, then display this data.

I'm trying to display an image to each object so I put the pass in the json file like this:

```
"image": "../camera.png"
```

then I used a map function to read the objects and display it..

```
items.map(eachitem => {
*..//code statments*
eachitem.image=require(eachitem.image)
});
```

and here's the error:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../camera.png'

I'm sure that the path is correct because before I put it in json file it worked right, so any help please?

json file path: "C:/Users/Admin/Projects/planner/demo/src/itemsData.json"

image path: "C:/Users/Admin/Projects/planner/demo/src/catalog/items-catalog/item1.png"

Comment: What are you using to bundle your app?

Comment: I think the path is incorrect. Could you include your directory structure?

Comment: @mahan the thing is when I made an array inside the .js file it worked well, but when I changed it to json file, this error occurred

Comment: Yes, please share your directory structure. Maybe the relative path from your JSON file is different.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a client application that runs on the browser. you can't use `require` in the browser. You are probably using some bundler like webpack.
Can you please share some light on your situation?

Comment: @AtinSingh I updated the question and put both paths in it

Comment: We need informations about your bundler to help you. If you run the command to build/serve your project via npm or yarn please share the "scripts" object in your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

First import the json object

```
import ItemsData from '../path/to/file/itemsData.json'
```

When you loop, loop through the ItemsData object.

```
ItemsData.map(item => {
 // item.image gives you the img url
});
```